# global and local variable

Tags: c, global, local

```
#include<>
int calc(int,int,char);
void main()
{
    int a,b;
    char c;
    printf("enter 2 nos");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    printf("enter op");
    scanf("%s",&c);
    printf("the ans is %d\n",calc(a,b,c));
}
int calc(int a,int b,char c)
{
    int ans;
    switch(c)
    {
        case'+':ans=a+b;break;
        case'-':ans=a-b;break;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

why does this program give the output as b...it works when i give a, b and c as global variables...what change should i do if i want them as local variables...using functions

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for why `void main()` is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char c;
...
scanf("%s",&c);
```

Is plain wrong, even if `c` is a global variable.

Your `scanf` will take input from the keyboard and store the string you type at the address given as second parameter (in your case the address of `c`). But `c` has only space for a single character, and your string inputted with `scan` will take at least 2 characters (the one you type and th terminating zero).

In your case you get undefined behaviour, which means that your program may

- appear to work
- crash each time you run it
- appear to work with a certain string you type, and crash with another
- or any other odd behaviour

You need this:

```
char c[10];
...
scanf("%9s",c);
...
printf("the ans is %d\n",calc(a,b,c[0]));
```

which lets allows you to input a string of length 9 (9 characters + terminating zero = 10).

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s",&c);` causes **undefined behavior**. You are storing at least two characters `['+', '\0']` and you have only allocated space for one.

You might consider `scanf(" %c", &c);`. Note that I intentionally added a space in the format string to eat any whitespace that the user might include.

Comment: but it works when i declare a and b out of the main..i mean as global variables

Comment: It's still undefined behavior if it's a global variable. A possible result from undefined behavior is that your code appears to work.

Comment: i want it to work when i declare a,b and c within main..how do i do that?

Comment: @AishwaryaShah by following the advice in this answer